# Dice-based game of craps

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to implement function craps() that takes no argument, simulates one game of craps, and returns 1 if the player won and 0 if the player lost.

Here is the rule: the game starts with the player throwing a pair of standard, six-sided dice. If the player rolls a total of 7 or 11, the player wins. If the player rolls a total of 2, 3, or 12, the player loses. For all other roll values, the player will repeatedly roll the pair of dice until either she rolls the initial value again (in which case she wins) or 7 (in which case she loses)

Here is the code I get. I keep getting 0, but I can't find where I made a mistake.

```
def craps():
    ''' () -> int

    Return 1 if the player won and 0 if the player lost.

    >>> craps()
    0
    >>> craps()
    1
    >>> craps()
    1
    '''
    import random
    dice = random.randrange(1, 7) + random.randrange(1, 7)
    if dice == 2 or dice == 3 or dice == 12:
        return 0
    elif dice == 7 or dice == 11:
        return 1
    else:
        dice1 = random.randrange(1, 7) + random.randrange(1, 7)
        while dice1 != dice or dice1 != 7:
            dice1 = random.randrange(1, 7) + random.randrange(1, 7)
        if dice1 == dice:
            return 1
        elif dice1 == 7:
            return 0
```

And when I call craps(), I get 0 all the time.

Comment: You've said "Here is the code" but not posted it. This makes it hard to help.

Comment: Is this a function (you've not posted a `def`)? Try printing the values `dice` and `dice1` when you set them.

Comment: Of note, if I put the indented code in a function and call it, I get 1. Not 0.

Comment: @doctorlove: Sorry, this is a function. I did a lot of changes and I still got 0. Do I need to make somewhere indented ?

Comment: If you can post the exact code that keeps giving you zero, showing how you call it, it will be easier to try to help.

Comment: @doctorlove: I've edited it. Is that Ok? I don't know how to type the exact format. Sorry about that. I just call craps() and it returns 0

Comment: If you `import random` outside the function, does anything change?

Comment: @doctorlove: It doesn't work. Maybe I should change the 'or' in while-loop into 'and'.

Comment: @doctorlove: I think it works now. I start to get both 1 and 0.

Comment: @doctorlove: Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Good job, you were very close. I found your problem, it was your while statment. I took the liberty of making your program a bit more readable since dice is plural. Also I moved your import random out of the craps() function. I added the print just for error checking:

```
#Return 1 if the player won and 0 if the player lost.

import random


def craps():
    die1 = random.randrange(1,7)
    die2 = random.randrange(1,7)
    dice = die1 + die2
    if dice == 2 or dice == 3 or dice == 12:
        return 0
   elif dice == 7 or dice == 11:
        return 1
   else:
        die1 = random.randrange(1, 7)
        die2 = random.randrange(1, 7)
        dice2 = die1 + die2
        while dice2 != dice and dice2 != 7:
            die1 = random.randrange(1, 7)
            die2 = random.randrange(1, 7)
            dice2 = die1 + die2
        if dice2 == dice:
            return 1
        elif dice2 == 7:
            return 0


print(str(craps()))
```